# k-means initial centers determine the result?

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, k-means

K-means clustering is a common way for clustering. Suppose there are N points for K-means clustering, i.e., N points should be divided into K groups where points in each group have similarity with each other.

And we should assign value to initial centers before `K-means clustering` process, Here I choose randomly K points from the whole points, and the program get different ouput for each run. Why will this lead different results and how do I know which is the best classification?

Comment: Perform this N/K times, each time leave one test out and use it to benchmark the points you classified. This gives you a measure of how good your classification is. (Note: DO NOT choose the one out of those K with the best results, it doesn't say it's the best  classification - this is to test your classification).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Can you elaborate a bit on how exactly you'll benchmark? Initially I thought you were talking about a [validation set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validation_set#Rationale) (which I'm not sure how it will work, as the points are initially unlabelled), but now I'm not so sure any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, the k-means clustering algorithm doesn't necessarily produce an optimal result, thus that's already a fairly significant indicator that it might have different results from different starting points.

It really comes down to the fact that each cluster uses the points in its own cluster to determine where it should move to - if all the clusters find their way to the centre of their respective points, the algorithm will terminate, and there can be multiple ways this can happen.

Consider this example: (4 points indicated by `.` and 2 clusters indicated by `x`)

```
.         .                      .    x    .
x         x         versus       
.         .                      .    x    .
```

Both the left and the right side have converged, but they're clearly different (the one on the right is clearly worse).

To find the best one you can pick the result that minimizes the sum of square distances from the centres to each of the points classified under it (this is, after all, [the goal of k-means clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_algorithm#Description)).

Comment: perhaps genetic algorithm can help me choose the best commbination of initial centers, suppose we use an `N-size` array to express which point is choosen, i.e., `1` at `i-th` position says that `i-th` point is selected, could you tell me how to define the fitness function? I don't what is fit here?

Comment: @stonestrong Similarly, the fitness function could be the sum of square distances (which you again want to minimize).

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to run several times your clustering algorithm with K different centroids for your clusters,  initialized with K points randomly taken from your data set.

Then your best solution will be the one that minimizes the sum of the square distance between a point and the centroid of the cluster it belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

K-means works by trying to improve the answer that it is given until it reaches a local optimum, but there is a good argument that there is no single global optimum, and therefore no single local optimum. If there was, then every K-means algorithm on the same dataset would always converge to the same answer. But cannot happen, because if I take an answer after K-means has converged and renumber the clusters I get another answer which is different but scores exactly as well as the answer I started with, so there are in fact multiple global optima.

There are various schemes to provide starting points to K-means, which you might try as well as choosing starting points at random. Some recent ones claim improvements in speed, such as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means%2B%2B. There are some tests of simpler methods at http://jihe.net/downloads/papers/he04ijcnn.pdf